# Intersection of polygons

Tags: geopandas, intersection, geodataframe

I have a brown polygon which intersects two purple polygons:

[image]

I d like to make sure that the brown polygon (64981Cas) is allocated to the purple polygon with the highest intersection area (the polygon below not the polygon above).

```
gdf= gpd.sjoin(left_df=brown_poly, right_df=purple_poly, how="left", predicate="intersects")
```

`gdf` will give two rows because there are two intersections. I am only looking for the intersection which has the highest common area.

Any idea?